# Equivalent to Windows getch() for Mac/Linux crashes

Tags: c, macos, crash, getch

I am using `getch()` and my app crashes instantly. Including when doing:

```
int main()
{
    getch();
}
```

I can't find the link but supposedly the problem is that it needs to turn off buffering or something strange along those lines, and I still want `cout` to work along with cross platform code.

I was told to use `std::cin.get()`, but I'd like the app to quit when a key is pressed, not when the user typed in a letter or number then press enter to quit.

Is there any function for this? The code must work under Mac (my os) and Windows.

---

Linking/compiling is not an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267250/equivalent-to-getch-mac-linux-crash#comment14636199_267281); I include `<curses.h>` and link with `-lcurses` in XCode, while Windows uses `<conio.h>`.

Comment: Note that 'cout' is a C++ construct.  Although the answers thus far are primarily for C, they will also apply to C++.  And std::cin.get() would be stuck waiting for a line of terminal input - the 'Hit Enter' syndrome - just as much as getchar() or any other standard I/O function.

Comment: I had a similar problem, This [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421860/capture-characters-from-standard-input-without-waiting-for-enter-to-be-pressed?noredirect=1&lq=1) might help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you looked in `<curses.h>` to see what the `getch()` function does?

Hint: OSX and Linux are not the same as Windows.

Specifically, as a macro in `<curses.h>`, we find:

```
#define getch() wgetch(stdscr)
```

Now, there appears, on your system, to be an actual function `getch()` in the curses library, but it expects `stdscr` to be set up, and that is done by the curses initialization functions (`initscr()` and relatives), and that is signally not done by your code.  So, your code is invoking undefined behaviour by calling curses routines before the correct initialization is done, leading to the crash.

(Good hint from dmckee - it helped get the link line out of acidzombie24, which was important.)

To get to a point where a single key-stroke can be read and the program terminated cleanly, you have to do a good deal of work on Unix (OSX, Linux).  You would have to trap the initial state of the terminal, arrange for an `atexit()` function - or some similar mechanism - to restore the state of the terminal, change the terminal from cooked mode into raw mode, then invoke a function to read a character (possibly just `read(0, &c, 1)`), and do your exit.  There might be other ways to do it - but it certainly will involve some setup and teardown operations.

One book that might help is [Advanced Unix Programming, 2nd Edn](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131411543) by Mark Rochkind; it covers terminal handling at the level needed.  Alternatively, you can use `<curses.h>` properly - that will be simpler than a roll-your-own solution, and probably more reliable.

Answer (score 3):

You have not exhibited a

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

or

```
#include <curses.h>
```

or similar line. Are you sure that you are linking against a library that *includes* `getch()`?

Comment: linking/compiling is not an issue, i include curses and do -lcurses in xcode. window uses conio.h

Answer (score 2):

Use the cin.get() function for example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char input = cin.get();

  cout << "You Pressed: " << input;
}
```

The program would then wait for you to press a key.

Once you have, the key you pressed would be printed to the screen.

Comment: Or just use getchar() function

Answer (score 1):

You can use stty to set raw mode input on unix-like systems:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    // for unix
    system("stty raw");

    while (1) {
        char c = getchar();
        // use e to exit
        if(c == 'e') {
            system("stty cooked");
            exit(0);
        } else {
            for (int i = 0;i < 10;i++)
                printf("%c ",c);
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Don't forget to use `system(stty cooked)` to set it back, cause if not your terminal will behave weirdly.

Answer (score -1):

The `getch` function is not available on Unix-like systems, but you can replace it with console commands through your compiler with the `system` function.

Usage:

In Windows you can use `system("pause");`

In Unix-like systems (such as OSX) you can use `system("read -n1 -p ' ' key");`

Note: `system` is declared in `<stdlib.h>`.

Comment: this will pause your program until the user hits a key -any key- just as in `getch();`

Comment: Please refrain from suggesting `system()` calls. It's bad programming practice and has bad side effects.