# wait for an Input just 1 second otherwise continue

Tags: c, ubuntu, wait, continue

I wanted just to implement this algorithm by C  on Ubuntu:

wait for a certain time to receive input from keyboard, so, by getting possible input or by over time, the program should be continued.

I dont have any clue to do that! 
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513734/problem-with-kbhitand-getch-for-linux

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839508/test-if-stdin-has-input-for-c-windows-and-or-linux/6839581#6839581

Answer (score 0):

See the manual for the [alarm()](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/en/man2/alarm.2.html) and [signal()](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/en/man2/signal.2.html) functions. You can easily timeout any code without using any threads or processes.

Comment: First of all thank you for reply. I think, in both solutions, run of program goes to wait state. But, my program has a graphic, which should be refreshed every .4 seconds, through this refreshing, a user may enter a key, so now, screen should be refreshed, to show the user's impact.

Answer (score 0):

The common way to do that is with [`select()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/select.html) or [`poll()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/poll.html):

```
struct pollfd fd = {STDIN_FILENO, POLLIN};
switch(poll(&fd, 1, 1)){
case -1:
     die("poll failed");
     break;
case 0:
     //timed out...
     break;
default:
     //read from stdin 
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you for reply.
I think, in both solutions, run of program goes to wait state. But, my program has a graphic, which should be refreshed every .4 seconds, through this refreshing, a user may enter a key, so now, screen should be refreshed, to show the user's impact.