# eclipse C++ alternative for getch()

Tags: c++, eclipse, getch

I am using C++ under Eclipse. With the Borland compiler I have used getch() function to take user input without showing what was entered.

The getch() function is not working under Eclipse.

Is there another way to get the user input without displaying on the screen the symbols which he enters?

Comment: Numerous duplicates, e.g. [What is equivalent to getch() & getche() in Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469139/what-is-equivalent-to-getch-getche-in-linux), [Problem with kbhit() and getch() for Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513734/problem-with-kbhitand-getch-for-linux) and [Alternative function in iostream.h for getch() of conio.h?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377403/alternative-function-in-iostream-h-for-getch-of-conio-h).

Comment: Eclipse is not a compiler, it's an IDE. You should specify with what compiler/platform you're working.

Answer (score 0):

Borland included `getch()` in their CRT libraries for backward compatibility with MS-DOS.

It's just a wrapper around the Win32 API. Borland usually ships the CRT source code with their compilers, so you can see how it is implemented there.

Comment: Or if you care about portability then just use `getchar()`.

Comment: @Paul R - getchar() function show the user input. I do not want to display it on the screen.