# How to properly use setvbuf in C?

Tags: c, io, buffering

I would like to set my input stream as unbuffered using `setvbuf()` but I don't really know how to use it.

I've done some googling and found that when you set a stream to unbuffered, the buffer and size parameters are ignored, as said by [this article](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_setvbuf.htm).

Here is my code:

```
#include "structures.h"
#include "functions.h"

char choice;
int option;

int main(void) {
    while(1) {
        puts("============================================Select an Option============================================");
        puts("1. Create Linked List");
        puts("2. Display items");
        puts("3. Add item to the beginning");
        puts("4. Add item to the end");
        puts("5. Add item in the middle");
        puts("6. Delete item from the beginning");
        puts("7. Delete item from the end");
        puts("8. Delete item from the middle");
        puts("9. Exit");
        printf(">>> ");

        setvbuf(stdin, _IONBF);
        choice = getchar();
        cleanStdin();
        option = choice - '0';

        //...
    }
}
```

The article says they're ignored but I still get an error about not enough parameters, so I don't know what to put in there. Can someone help me please?

Comment: The arguments are ignored, but you still need to pass them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *fake* parameters:

```
setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

This, though, will not allow you to read charaters from the terminal without pressing <kbd>`Enter`</kbd>, this a terminal problem, not a buffering one, for that you need something else.

You can you use `ncurses`, which is the advised route, but you can also use the accepted answer in this post [What is the equivalent to getch() & getche() in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7469139/6865932) which allows you to do exactly that.

You can see it working here: https://replit.com/@anastaciu/ConcernedAncientMenu

Comment: Thank you for helping but for some reason, I still have to press enter to send the characters to stdin. If I'm not mistaken, unbuffered input means that input is sent to the program right when I press a key right? Or is there something else wrong?

Comment: @MatthewSchell, that would be nice, but no, you still have to press enter.

Comment: @MatthewSchell, the *problem* is in the terminal, not the buffering, you need to use something else, if your in a linux machine I would advise ncurses.

Comment: so something like `getch()`?

Comment: @MatthewSchell, yes, that's from windows `conio.h` isn't it?

Comment: Well I'm on a Mac so it would be ncurses.h for me

Comment: @MatthewSchell, yes, you'll find that it's very easy to use once you get used to it, maybe there are other ways, check this post https://stackoverflow.com/q/7469139/6865932, it's quite old, so some deprecation might be going on there, but it's worth checking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231468/discussion-between-matthew-schell-and-anastaciu).

Comment: @MatthewSchell the accepted answer in the link works perfectly, did you try it? I left a live demo in my answer.

Comment: for some reason it works in repl but not in CLion, I'll have to investigate that but I'll mark it as accepted anyway. Thanks!

Comment: @MatthewSchell That's indeed weird, try running it on a separate terminal window, IDE's sometimes don't alllow these to work properly

Comment: Doesn't work on a different terminal window either, except now i can't delete the first character i input.

Comment: IDK man, it seems that it's a problem local to your environment, try this test routine https://stackoverflow.com/a/1513806/6865932, see if it works, otherwise, maybe going for ncurses can be a easier way out.