# Listen for a keypress without stalling the entire program in C

Tags: c, input, keyboard

I'm trying to make a game where objects move when certain keys have been pressed. But I want to implement it so that stuff is moving and loops are running all the time. So far the keyboard input functions such as scanf and getchar have all been waiting for me to press a key until they allow the program to continue. How do i listen for key presses without stalling the program (without using threads)?

Comment: This is covered in the C FAQ list: http://c-faq.com/osdep/readavail.html

Comment: What Ben said. Or on unix clones, you can put the terminal into non-canonical mode ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29723614/3386109)). On MS systems, you can use `kbhit` to check for keyboard input, and `getch` to read the key.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way of implementing this using a loop.
The following program will *do something else* in a loop, and in every pass it will check if a key has been pressed. The pressed key will then be stored to a variable `c`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void) {
    char c = '\0';

    while (1) { 
        if (kbhit()) { 
            c = getch(); 
        }
        /* If a key has been pressed */
        if (c != '\0') {
            /* Do something */
            c = '\0'; // and put it back to \0
        }

        /* Do something else */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Note:** This solution works only on Windows and other operating systems where the header file "*conio.h*" can be included

Comment: kbhit() is not defined as part of the ANSI C standard.

Comment: Efficient IO handling is what threads, (well, preemptive multitasking OS),  are good at.

Comment: I get the following error messages when I try to run this code.

LINK ERROR: unresolved external symbol '_kbhit' in module 'square' of file 'square.obj'

Comment: @VanGo What operating system are you using?

Comment: If you are using Linux, check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29335758/using-kbhit-and-getch-on-linux) to see an example illustrating how ncurses could be used like the conio example.