# How to input an int or char from the terminal without having to press "enter" on both Windows and Unix

Tags: c

Basically I want to input a pass code composed of 4 digits from the terminal.  I have some sloppy solutions but I want something clean.  I want the user to write a digit and I'll put it in an array without having to press "enter".  And then the user will give the second digit and I'll put it in the array... So for example it will give some thing like this:

```
>1      the array [1, 0, 0, 0]
>12     the array [1, 2, 0, 0]
>123    the array [1, 2, 3, 0]
>1234   the array [1, 2, 3, 4]
>the rest of the program
```

Comment: Depends on the operating system. Which operating system are you using?

Comment: One easy way is `ncurses`.

Comment: MSVC has non-standard library functions [`_getch()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getch-getwch?view=vs-2017) and [`_getche()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getche-getwche?view=vs-2017). I have always been mystifed by the lack of a single-key entry in standard C. In this case though, the input cannot be redirected as it is not through `stdin`.

Comment: What platform are you on? There isn't a single soultion for all platforms. Input from the terminal is usually line buffered, and disabling line buffering can only be done in a  platform specific manner.

Comment: @user3386109 @ Ankush I use Windows but i care about knowing how on Unix based systems also

Comment: MSVC also has the non-blocking [`_kbhit()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/kbhit?view=vs-2017) which is useful to check when you don't want to commit to the blocking functions I mentioned.

Comment: @SteveSummit ncurses looks great, but i am on a project and i can't just restart it using it but thanks tho !

Comment: On unix systems, you can [set the terminal into non-canonical mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723205/).

Comment: [C FAQ list answer](http://c-faq.com/osdep/cbreak.html). (Somewhat dated, though.)